# Is it common for tutors to be concerned they might teach themselves out of a job?

Tags: tutoring

I'm tutoring a student. They originally hired me after failing an exam, and now, after six months, they nearly scored an A in the finals (they should have gotten the 'A' too, but the lecturer set a bad question and then refused to admit there was no correct answer).

Naturally I'm happy they've improved by so much, but now I'm curious: strong students don't generally need tutors. They are more than capable of studying on their own. I could potentially be teaching myself out of a job. I'm lucky in the sense that I don't *need* this job, so I don't *have* to be concerned, but someone else might.

I'm wondering if tutors are concerned that if they teach too well they might lose their job, and if so, whether they hold back (that would be unethical??).

Comment: You are asking for a prediction of what is in the minds of unknown persons? No, not everyone is ethical.

Comment: @Buffy: there might well be research on this which Allure might be interested in... but asking for specific research is off-topic, and as you write, mind-reading is so as well.

Comment: Maybe tutors should keep in mind that, like in any service job, past successes help with marketing (often by word of mouth in this context) and justification when setting future prices.

Comment: I’d say that, no, it is not common. There are more students needing help next semester, and if you do a good job you will be in demand.

Comment: In my experience students are more likely to drop a tutor because they didn't improve! They become discouraged with their studies, leading them to drop out or change majors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you teach people that become better than you: you are a success! You are a great teacher! Congratulations!

You are worried that they will take your spot? Or someone elses? Is that the new academic ideal that we now embrace holding people back (or not giving them the best possible support) so that they may not overshadow their peers? There is a thinking school that favours that, and it will give you mediocrity and stagnation. Is this what people would be paying the exorbitant student fees for?

Healthy competition is a good thing; only when society tips over and tramples over the less fortunate, it becomes a problem. In academia, striving for excellence used to be (and should be) the norm. Striving for excellence does not preclude compassion for the less fortunate, but - in turn - compassion does not mean holding back the capable ones from achieving their potential.

Is it a problem if a student excels the teacher? Let's see:

Socrates: Plato

Sommerfeld: Werner Heisenberg, Wolfgang Pauli, Peter Debye, and Hans Bethe (all Nobel Prize winners, unlike Sommerfeld)

Aristotle: Alexander the Great (not intellectually, necessarily, but on a wide scale of abilities)

John Wheeler: Richard Feynman

If you are a teacher who makes people excel, you are a success. No matter where, your skill will be always in demand. Even in industry, capable coaches are amongst the most valuable people there are, because they find and (in a way) "generate" excellence, not as a one-off, but on a regular basis.